# Question about honest and dishonest function

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I am currently reading Functional Programming in C# by Enrico Buonanno. Chapter 3 contains an exercise (I will shorten the exercise to the relevant parts):

```
// 5.  Write an implementations for the method in the `AppConfig` class below.
// Assume settings are of type string, numeric or date.

public class AppConfig
{
    NameValueCollection source;

    //public AppConfig() : this(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings) { }

    public AppConfig(NameValueCollection source) => this.source = source;

    public Option<T> Get<T>(string name)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Your implementation here...");
    }
}
```

The solution I came up with was

```
public Option<T> Get<T>(string name)
    {
        try { 
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(source.Get(name), typeof(T)));
        } 
        catch { 
            return None; 
        };
    }
```

The author's solution is

```
public Option<T> Get<T>(string key)
        => source[key] == null
           ? None
           : Some((T)Convert.ChangeType(source[key], typeof(T)));
```

But isn't this a dishonest function? I can have a config file that contains a key "SomeNumber" with a value of "not a number", so if I use this method like `Get<int>("SomeNumber")` this will throw, whereas my implementation will return None. Alternatively, I might also have an entry with key "SomeString" with value of "Goodbye World" which I erroneously try to retrieve by calling `Get<int>("SomeString")`.

You might argue that throwing is actually the desired result, as this is a developer error, which should be highlighted.

Thoughts?

Comment: *You might argue that throwing is actually the desired result, as this is a developer error, which should be highlighted.* – Yes, that. You can represent it with a value instead of an exception, but probably not the same value as a missing key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Throwing is actually the desired result* Yes. The pattern used in .NET is that not-throwing methods are called `TrySomething` (e.g. `TryParse`, `TryGetValue`...)

I'll add that in your case, the method suggested in the book has *three* possible "return values" (I'll use double quotes here):

- Key found and of the right type
- Key not found
- Key found but of the wrong type (exception is thrown)

while yours has only two:

- Key found and of the right type
- Key not found or key found but of the wrong type

so your method makes not-clear if the value is simply missing (that could be ok, an optional value) or if there is an error in the configuration.